# How to get id from list in dictionary in the serializer django

Tags: django, python-3.x, list, dictionary, django-rest-framework

```
CHOICE_FIELD_SET = {
    'dependent': [
        {'id': 1, 'name': "Spouse"},
        {'id': 2, 'name': "Children"},
        {'id': 3, 'name': "Parents"}
    ]
}
```

This is my constant.py

```
 @staticmethod
    def validate_dependent_type(dependent_type):
        if dependent_type > util_constants.CHOICE_FIELD_SET['dependent'].extend('id'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Dependent can be of three types only")
        return dependent_type
```

this is my serializer.py

how to validate up to id 3 only
hope you understand the question if not please ask in comment

Comment: So you need to check  the dependent id is greater than 3 ?

Comment: i need to limit if dependent type present in this list then only execute otherwise show an error

Answer (score 0):

```
CHOICE_FIELD_SET = {
'dependent': [
    {'id': 1, 'name': "Spouse"},
    {'id': 2, 'name': "Children"},
    {'id': 3, 'name': "Parents"}
]
```

}

```
def validate_dependent_type(dependent_type):
    # validate if dependent_type > dependant id list
    if dependent_type > max([d.get('id') for d in util_constants.CHOICE_FIELD_SET.get('dependent', [0])] or [0]):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Dependent can be of three types only")
    return dependent_type
```

Checks if depenpdant_type is greater than the dependant id list. The above code works even if the dependant list is empty.